# How to join two tables in MySQL and display results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've started to learn PHP & MySQL myself and could not understand the below issue. I have created 2 table shown below,

- enents       => evnt_id, evnt_nm_, date, venue, details
- participants => p_id, p_nm, organization, contact

I just want to join these two tables in order to make search that has two fields where we can select event and participants and make the search. Please anyone help me first to join the table which is appropriate for this scenario.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are these two tables _related_ to each other?  It's not clear to me how to join them together.

Comment: You must have event id in participants table also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add common id for both and get like this i put this code only for example

- events => **id**, evnt_id, evnt_nm_, date, venue, details
- participants => p_id,**common_id**,  p_nm, organization, contact

  ```
  SELECT events.id,events.evnt_id, events.evnt_nm_, events.date, events.venue, events.details FROM events INNER JOIN participants ON articipants.common_id=events.id;
  ```

It is for inner join

Comment: Thanks very much. Your help is much appreciated. Can I do it like this? Add the 'evnt_nm' column in the 'participants' table and join two tables together based on 'evnt_nm'?

Comment: Yes of course. We just want one common id for both table.

Comment: Thanks very much. sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Joining 'em makes no sense - they're not related.

What does make a lot of sense - is getting into this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided and got a general idea, but it hasn't fulfilled my requirement. Anyway, thanks for the time mate.